# Drupal's .info file doesn't load multiple js files

Tags: javascript, drupal

Although I included multiple .js files in Drupal 7's .info file as advised, only the first ones do load - up to 
*scripts[] = js/jquery.cycle2.min.js* 
but not further. Changing the order doesn't help, it seems to stop loading every time at the first cycle-js file. 
What am I missing there? Or is it only possible to include max 3 .js for some reason/setting?

```
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
stylesheets[all][] = media.css
scripts[] = js/custom.js
scripts[] = js/jquery.cycle2.min.js
scripts[] = js/jquery.cycle2.caption2.min.js
scripts[] = js/jquery.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Try another way to include js file .
/your_theme/template.php

```
    function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . 'js/custom.js');
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . 'js/jquery.cycle2.min.js');
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . 'js/jquery.cycle2.caption2.min.js');
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . 'js/jquery.js');
        $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); 
      }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following function to add JS on your site:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (true) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme.js');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme1.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); // necessary in D7?
  }
}
```

Comment: if (true) { ???
put your condition where you need to apply this section.